# ZF2 dynamic routing

Tags: php, controller, routes, zend-framework2

I have problem with the routing in ZF2. I want to make dynamic routing for the software, that I'm making. 
For example: 
This is the URL: `http://localhost:8080/application/index.json/`
And this is my module.config (router part):

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'restful' => array(
                'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'       => '/:module/[:controller[/:action][.:formatter][/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => array(

                        'module' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'formatter'  => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'         => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                    ),


                ),
            ), 

      ), 
 ),
```

Everything is working fine, but when I create new controller, have to add it to controllers['invokables'] setting in module.config.

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        'cloud' => 'Application\Controller\CloudController',
    ),
),
```

So the question is, how to automate the controllers['invokables'] to process requests dynamically, without describing every controller in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast and dirty, but you get the idea.

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

        $eventManager->attach (MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function (MvcEvent $e) {
            $controller_loader = $e->getApplication ()->getServiceManager ()->get ('ControllerLoader');

            $controller = $e->getRouteMatch ()->getParam ('controller');
            $controller_class = '\Application\Controller\\'.ucfirst ($controller).'Controller';

            // Add service locator to the controller
            $controller_object = new $controller_class;
            $controller_object->setServiceLocator ($e->getApplication ()->getServiceManager ());
            // ------------------------------------
            $controller_loader->setService ($controller, $controller_object);
        });
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but after your code, I have postProcessor function in which i made: $di = $e->getTarget()->getServiceLocator()->get('di');

If use your routing I get this error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object. After a little debugging, I figure out that the "$e->getTarget()->getServiceLocator()"  is NULL.

Comment: You should add Service Locator to the Controller then. See my update.

Comment: @akond So it is impossible to achieve this with configuration only? And why routing with :controller parameter works on skelleton application Application module (but not any other modules)? https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php